# BIP 32 Public Parent Key -> Public Child Key

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

Reading the BIP 32 section of how to generate Public child key from Public parent key, I got stuck in the following:

> The returned child key Ki is point(parse256(IL)) + Kpar.

As I could understand **point(p)** is the Elliptical Curve multiplication which will output X and Y coords, so how can I add them with Kpar? Also, it should return me a Compressed public key right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A public key is an elliptic curve point. So `K_par` is also an elliptic curve point. You can then just do a EC point add to add the point given by `point(p)` with `K_par` to get a new point, which is also a public key.

Comment: So if I have K_par as compressed I need to recover Y value using `ModPow(a, (p+1)/4, p)` ?

Comment: @AllanRomanato Yes, converting a compressed serialization of a point to a point requires recovering the Y coordinate (and negating if necessary, to make the oddness match up).

Answer (score 1):

The addition operation in that context refers to the Elliptic Curve group operation ("point addition").

The child key returned is a point, not a serialization. So the question of whether it's compressed or not is not technically relevant. In practice, every time a serialization of a point is used in BIP32, it is compressed though.